# PRISM to angular migration feasible or not

Tags: angularjs, angular, silverlight, prism

I have an old project which has been done by someone in `Silverlight with PRISM`. I want to migrate front-end to `angular2`. Is it feasible? Because I am totally un-aware of PRISM. Is PRISM works on traditional old form submission or with webservices? I am familiar with angular2 and dont know much about PRISM.
please guide.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the technical aspects are concerned, these are different frameworks and your team will have some learning curve if you dont already know angular2. 
Yes PRISM works with services and it help you design Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) desktop applications in conjunction with MVVM pattern. PRISM is about separation of concerns and loose coupling and helps you design applications using loosely coupled components that can evolve independently.
To me, migration is more of a strategic decision, if you have healthy customer base and your app is going to stay for quite some time then at some stage you have to leave the older technologies and move towards the trending ones.

Comment: I want to keep the backend as same and want to implement front end with Angular. Is it possible? . The think is that I do not know PRISM and angular I am familar with angular2.please guide me

Comment: What are you using in the backend?

Comment: backend I am planning to make use of PRISM webservices. Is PRISM provides web services? Is it feasible?

Comment: Prism is a pattern for WPF and silverlight applications, web services are not the part of prism, normally WCF services were used with it. Check your project code i guess it will be with WCF services on the backend.

Comment: Thanks bro. So basically it is communicated with WCF services right? Can I call WCF services just like webservices from angular?Is WCF provides REST/SOAP? please help.

Comment: WCF is rest enabled you can use WCF. Better approach is go for dotnet 5 webserver which can be cross platform and then let it communicate with Angular on one side and WCF on other. You may have to convert the WCF models to dotnet standard, but with dotnet 5 i believe its not required.